# Cannot block IP access to wp-login.php on Nginx

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx-location

I'm experiencing attacks to wp-login.php so I decided to protect it. Here is the code:

```
location ~ ^/(wp-admin|wp-login\.php) {
allow x.x.x.x;
deny all;
}
```

It protects wp-admin directory OK but the protection of wp-login.php doesn't work. It allows me to access the wp-login.php whatever IP I use. Any idea ?

Comment: have you tried with a IP number out of your network or you can use your firewall to block the IP (just an idea)

Comment: I suppose you have already restarted your server? `/etc/init.d/nginx reload`

Comment: Yes, I reloaded nginx as well as tested IP. I tested it on live server

Answer (score 0):

There is actually a plugin that may handle this for you, Limit Login Attempts (https://wordpress.org/plugins/limit-login-attempts/). This plugin,  is old but still fully functional and is a recommended plugin to have.

You can configure it to do the following:

1. After login attempts the person is locked out, by IP, for 20 minutes.
2. After 4 lockouts, the IP is then banned for 48 hours.
3. Login attempts reset after 12 hours.